# Should a virtualhost always use the naked domain as the ServerName?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, domain

When setting up a virtual host for `example.com`, and wanting to use `www.example.com` as my **preferred** domain, is it standard practice to use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

... wherein my preferred domain is an alias?

Does it matter if I were to switch the values of the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`? As far as I can tell, they are interchangeable (with the exception that you can specify multiple server aliases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know switching the values of the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` normally makes no difference in how your sites will operate.

As mentioned in the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) ***only when*** [`UseCanonicalName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) is set to a ***non-default value***, you'll see the value of ServerName (rather than whatever URL was used to reach your site) getting used when creating self-referential redirection URL's.
You'll see  self-referential redirection URL's for instance if the users type a ServerAlias hostname and a URL which is a directory, such as `http://www.example.com/splat`, without the trailing slash, then Apache httpd will redirect them to `http://example.com/splat/`.

Otherwise you'll only see the value of the ServerName directive in the output of `apachectl -S` and in error messages as the standard [templates for friendly error messages](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/docs/error) include the ServerName  from [`include/bottom.html`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/docs/error/include/bottom.html)  to customise them:

> Title: 404 Not Found
>
> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /some/page was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at **example.com** port 80

---

There are some [valid technical arguments](http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/) to use `www.example.com` and you may want to do this instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / www.example.com 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.org www.example.net 
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```